# Can an Adventurers League character or party reimburse a PC for casting revivify?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-adventurers-league, wealth, resurrection

## The Situation

One PC just died. Fortunately, another PC is a cleric that has *revivify* prepared, an unused 3rd-level spell slot, and 300gp of diamonds they purchased before the session. They cast *revivify* and bring the dead PC back. The newly-revived PC is grateful and wants to reimburse the cleric, who just spent four sessions worth of gold.

## The Problem

According to the Adventurers League Player's Guide (ALPG):

> Rewards and equipment can’t be given to another character, except as follows:
>
> - You may lend equipment and magic items to other characters at your table but must return it at the end of the session unless consumed (like a potion).
>
>   [...]
> - Characters may choose to divide the cost of NPC spellcasting services obtained during an adventure.
>
> *ALPG v8.2, page 3*

The revived PC cannot permanently (nor temporarily, I believe) give the cleric PC 300gp. The party also can't do so. Only NPC spellcasting services can be divided. They also can't buy 300gp of diamonds later and give them permanently to the cleric. The PC could probably *lend* the cleric diamonds to cast the spell, assuming they count as equipment instead of rewards.

**Must every PC pre-purchase 300gp of diamonds or a scroll of revivify, just so their clerics don't go broke?** What if the PC's death wasn't their fault, so the party wants to split the cost? One final wrinkle - **AL tables may have different players each week**. An answer that works in a convention one-shot is better than one that only works in a 20-week hardcover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yet another oversight in the new AL rules

There are no rules specifically allowing a transfer of money. You've already quoted the most relevant information; things can be *lent* to other party members.

Going back a ways, in a number of AL-legal dungeons, there were a few pages worth of how-to notes. I grabbed this from DDEX1-02, Secrets of Sokol Keep:

> **Character's Party Pays for Raise Dead.** As above, except that some or all of the 1,250 gp for the raise dead spell is paid for by the party at the end of the session. **Other characters are under no obligation to spend their funds to bring back a dead party member.**

But this is pre-season 8, so may not even be true any more. It also doesn't cover trading money back and forth between players.

At best, you can take the wording of *lend* and make the risen character pay back the cleric.

The cleric *lent* the diamond to the dead character. That character *lost* the diamond in the spell casting and now needs to buy a new diamond to give back.

But once again the rule you sited says that the player does not **have** to give back the lent item if it was *consumed*.

So I think the only **legal** AL way would be only the revived character can either give back 300gp, or buy a new diamond and give it back. And it must be done within the same gaming session.